# Json traverse logs characters and not key values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to iterate through a JSON object with the following code:

```
traverse(json, process);

//called with every property and it's value
function process(key, value) {
    console.log(key + " : " + value);
}

function traverse(o, func) {
    for (var i in o) {
        func.apply(this, [i, o[i]]);
        if (o[i] !== null && typeof (o[i]) == "object") {
            //going on step down in the object tree!!
            traverse(o[i], func);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON object:

```
{"breakfast_menu":{"food":[{"name":["Belgian Waffles"],"price":["$5.95"],"description":["Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup"],"calories":["650"]},{"name":["Strawberry Belgian Waffles"],"price":["$7.95"],"description":["Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream"],"calories":["900"]},{"name":["Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles"],"price":["$8.95"],"description":["Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream"],"calories":["900"]},{"name":["French Toast"],"price":["$4.50"],"description":["Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread"],"calories":["600"]},{"name":[  "Homestyle Breakfast"],"price":["$6.95"],"description":["Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns"],"calories":["950"]}]}}
```

The result it is printing for me is the following:

```
> 748 : s 
> 749 : t 
> 750 : , 
> 751 : 
> 752 : a 
> 753 : n 
> 754 : d 
> 755 : 
> 756 : o
> 757 : u 
> 758 : r 
> 759 : 
> 760 : e 
> 761 : v 
> 762 : e 
> 763 : r 
> 764 : - 
> 765 : p
```

my expected result is to print values like

```
> key : value
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON object?

Comment: well... first you need to convert the json string into an object. couldn't imagine why you would want to parse the string instead.

Comment: http://www.node-console.com/script/json-traverse-logs-characters-and-not-key-values - Does this look like what you're doing?

Comment: @AnotherDev this is more like what he's doing: http://www.node-console.com/script/json-traverse-logs-characters-and-not-key-values-1 based on the console output he's seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my JSON was an string and not an object. Here is the code that solved it:

```
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```